# How to define a macro containing a tabbed line (\+...\cr)?

Tags: macros, tex-core, plain-tex

```
\def\test{\+test\cr}
\test
\vfill
\eject
```

The above gives error:

```
...
Runaway definition?
->
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \test.
...
```

Answer (score 5):

`\+` is a outer macro, it cannot be used in the definition of another macro. In `plain.tex`, it is defined as

```
\outer\def\+{\tabalign}
```

You can use `\tabalign` instead. Say,

```
\def\test{\tabalign test\cr}
\test
\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

A different approach is to neutralize momentarily the outer macro:

```
\begingroup\let\+\relax
\gdef\test{\+test\cr}
\endgroup
```

It can be used for the outer macros that have no "inner" version like `\bye`, `\beginsection` or `\proclaim`.

```
\begingroup\let\beginsection\relax
\gdef\section#1{\beginsection#1\par}
\endgroup

\section{Title}
```

Of course `\csname beginsection\endcsname` would have worked too, as Joseph points out.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to put an outer control sequence inside a macro is `\noexpand`:

```
\edef\test{\noexpand\+...}
```

The `\noexpand` command prevents expansion in an `\edef` (expanding def), and also hide "outerness".

Comment: The usual way to include an `\outer` control sequence inside something else is to use `\csname` ... `\endcsname`, which does not also leave you worrying about expansion.

Comment: True. The advantage of using `\noexpand` is that it also allows the `\outer` control sequence to come in an argument, expandably: `\def\foo{\expandafter\fooo\noexpand} \def\fooo#1{...}` works even if `#1` is normally `\outer`. (I saw this in a solution of one of M.Downes exercises.)